# How to stop startup scripts from getting deleted on reboot in ONIE

Tags: init-script, buildroot

I'm running an open source "install environment", that acts as an enhanced boot loader utilizing facilities in a Linux/BusyBox environment called Open network install environment (ONIE). I want to run some scripts on every boot and I tried to do this by storing it in the `init.d` directory which is called from the `inittab` and consequently the `rcS` script. But whenever I store any script in the directory it gets deleted on reboot. Also I tried adding the commands in the scripts already present but they also get deleted leaving the original script as it. Also the OS is mostly ram based but I can store files in the `/mnt` mounted directory.

Comment: What is the output of `df /etc/init.d/` and of `cat /proc/mounts` ?

Comment: Output'cat /proc/mounts': **rootfs / rootfs rw,relatime,size=8191888k,nr_inodes=2047972 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=8191900k,nr_inodes=2047975,mode=755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=777 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/ssd1 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb3 /mnt/usb23 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb22 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0**

Comment: Output of 'df /etc/init.d/' : **Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on df: /etc/init.d: can't find mount point** I understand why the problem is occuring, it's because the init.d isn't mounted on ROM and is just RAM based. Is there a solution to this @Gilles

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. I'm not familiar with ONIE but generally these environments are built from a read-only image plus some means of runtime override in some form, so you can either rebuild the system image (re-run buildroot) or use whatever ONIE has for runtime override.

Comment: I think you answered my question @Gilles... I'll have to simply rebuild the system image, there is no other option. Thank you.